# Calculation of Fourier Transform derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\omega}\ F\{x(t)\}(\omega)= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\omega}(X(\omega))$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Hello to my Math Fellows,

Problem:
I am looking for a way to calculate w-derivative of Fourier transform, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\omega} F\{x(t)\}(\omega)$, in terms of regular Fourier transform, $X(\omega)=F\{x(t)\}(\omega)$.

Definition Based Solution (not good enough):
from the [Fourier Transform Definition](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/25905b02d53ae042b113c038d50ac131fcf020d0), I can find that the $\omega$-derivative of Fourier transform $x(t)$ is the Fourier transform of $t\cdot x(t)$ multiplied by $-j$:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\omega} F\{x(t)\}(\omega) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\omega}X(\omega )=-j F\{t x(t)\}(\omega)
$$

Question:
Taking into account the differentiation and duality properties of Fourier transform:
 [Fourier Transform Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIM0k.png)

is it possible to express the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\omega} F\{x(t)\}(\omega)$ in frequency domain using terms of $X(\omega)$ ???

Many Thanks,
Desperate Engineer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for suggestion. Would fix it. 
Can you please suggest something regarding the question ?

Comment: If the function $X$ is known, then what you're asking about is just its derivative $X'$.

Comment: @Maxim I am looking for general derivative for unknown x with implication to discrete subspace of sampled signals. I am looking for alternative way to calculate Fourier transform derivative for sampled signal rather than divided difference.